# Javascript equivalent of jQuery's .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

What is the javascript equivalent of jQuery's hide()?

```
$("#someID").hide();
```

is **equivalent** to:

```
 document.getElementById("#someID").style.visibility="hidden";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("#someID").style.display="none";
```

Comment: jQuery is pretty well documented (http://api.jquery.com/hide/)... "The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown, it will once again be displayed inline."

Comment: So it seems clear that you know how to work with the `style` object. So why didn't you just see which property was set after `.hide()`? Seriously, give some effort before asking.

Comment: you seem to be an expert of jquery @BlueSkies

Comment: @ParveezAhmed: Why do you say that?

Comment: I too agree with parveez

Comment: rosemary: With what? @ParveezAhmed failed to make a relevant point. *My* point was that if you had bothered to put forth a tiny bit of effort, you would have had your answer. It doesn't take a jQuery expert to do `alert(document.getElementById("someID").style.hidden);` to see if it was set. At least a minimal amount of effort is expected, and you failed to do event that.

Comment: I accept the truth @BlueSkies No excuse that I was in hurry is welcome! good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first paragraph of [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide#entry-longdesc):

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

Also, even if it wasn't documented, it could be confirmed by looking at [the source code for `show()`/`hide()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3ca883f863f8c4b3b1153e63ef40a8c2c523d399/src/css.js#L152).

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById("#someID").style.display="none";

Comment: thanxxx @Johan Nordli

Answer (score 0):

Is equal to :

```
document.getElementById("#someID").style.display="none";
```

when visibility:hidden; is used the elements still occupies space in the page but when you do it display:none; the element doesn't occupies any space in the page.